# Set both icon and text on tabs in sliding tab layout

Tags: android

I have implemented icons on tab in slidingtablayout but I want to implement both icons and text.

This is my slidintablayout.java file, I have edited it according to show icons on tab.

```
package com.example.lordvoldemort.tab;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give constant feedback as to
 * the user's scroll progress.
 * <p>
 * To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
 * {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
 * {@link #setViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is being used for.
 * <p>
 * The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to provide an array of colors
 * via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)}. The
 * alternative is via the {@link TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
 * which color is used for any individual position.
 * <p>
 * The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
 * providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
 */
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }


    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private int mTabViewImageViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link android.widget.TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;


    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */

    protected ImageView createDefaultImageView(Context context) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        int width = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount());
        imageView.setMinimumWidth(width);



        return imageView;
    }
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (MyFragmentPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;
            ImageView tabIconView = null;
/*  if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0 ) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);

      tabIconView = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewImageViewId);


            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }*/

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultImageView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabIconView == null && ImageView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabIconView = (ImageView) tabView;
                tabIconView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(adapter.getDrawable(i)));
            }


            if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == i) {
                tabIconView.setSelected(true);
            }
           /* if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }*/



          //  tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));

            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(false);
            }
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);

            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is Sep 2015, I recommend using TabLayout from android design library. :)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

To have icons and text, You could extend the Tablayout and override the

```
public void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(@NonNull PagerAdapter adapter) {
    this.removeAllTabs();
    int i = 0;
    for (int count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        this.addTab(this.newTab().setIcon(<YourIconHereForThisTab >).setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
    }
}
```

This would display the icon and text side by side. if you want to have them vertically aligned
Or, require any other customization. You can use setCustomView method on the tab.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int)

Like :

```
public void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(@NonNull PagerAdapter adapter) {
    this.removeAllTabs();
    int i = 0;
    for (int count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        this.addTab(this.newTab().setCustomView(<YourLayoutID>).setIcon(<YourIconHereForThisTab>).setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
    }
}
```

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675140/5348371

Comment: i tried but got an error like this."android.support.design.widget.TabLayout cannot be cast to com.example.lordvoldemort.tab2.IconicTabLayout"

Comment: use _com.example.lordvoldemort.tab2.IconicTabLayout_  in your xml file instead of TabLayout. Also, use the same in the code.

Comment: hey could u please help me with that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661681/tab-icon-and-text-both-using-android-design-support-library  i used other way but got stuck please help me

Comment: You have to use your new class `com.example.lordvoldemort.tab2.IconicTabLayout` in XML layout.

Comment: i want to add icon at the left of text rather than top of text, could please help me