# Change icon in Tablayout on selected and deselected state

Tags: android, icons, android-tablayout

Sorry  if this question have been asked before.

I want to change icon when it is selected in tab of tab layout. How can I do this using selector?.

*I have two tabs in my application on selected state icon should change.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabLayout selected Tab icon is not selected on start up:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392640/tablayout-selected-tab-icon-is-not-selected-on-start-up)

Comment: Pease try this 
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.selector);

Comment: Thanks @LvN it is working

Comment: I will add this as answer pls accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.selector);
```

Answer (score 6):

**1. create a custom tab selector-** You need to add both state selected true and false

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_fill"
            android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_line"
            android:state_selected="false"/>
    </selector>
```

**2. Add the custom tab selector drawable as the icon for tabItem**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/footer"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/female_colour">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_home"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
            android:icon="@drawable/tab_home"
            />
 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Code is Tested on Android version 7.1.1

Answer (score 3):

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.setIcon(selectedImageResources[tab.getPosition()]);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(pageTitles[tab.getPosition()]);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.setIcon(imageResources[tab.getPosition()]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

To make tab selector and deselector you can use this way

**1.Create Custom view and Inflate it:**

```
private View getTabView(int imgDrawable) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);
        ImageView imgTab = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTab);
        imgTab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgDrawable));

        return view;
    }
```

**2.Create drawable Selector**

tab_home_selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_deselected" />
    </selector>
```

**3.Insert in tab:**

```
tabDashboardLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDashboardLayout);        
        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        View tabView = getTabView(R.drawable.tab_home_selector);;
        tabDashboardLayout.addTab(tabDashboardLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabView));
```

For individual tab you to have create individual drawable selector and add to tab

Answer (score 0):

please Check these question you will get your answer

[TabLayout selected Tab icon is not selected on start up:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392640/tablayout-selected-tab-icon-is-not-selected-on-start-up)

[Change icon and title color when selected in android design library TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755693/change-icon-and-title-color-when-selected-in-android-design-library-tablayout)