# how i can add icon to page title android java

Tags: java, android

how i can add  icon to my page title ? i had try to add a drwable but when i use app there isn't a icon but a text to position of icon

```
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }
    Drawable myDrawable;
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha);
                return ("Messaggi "+myDrawable);
            case 1:
                return "File ";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getPageTitle()` allows you to configure only text, not icon. You can see that return type of the function is `CharSequence`. If you want to set icon you need to do it manually. Check this question: [Tab icon and text both using android design support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661681/tab-icon-and-text-both-using-android-design-support-library)