# How to make vertical tab layout

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

Is there any way to make my tab layout in vertical mode?

[image]

i tried to make this tab layout in vertical mode, i search in anywhere but never find the way to make it in vertical mode.

nb : i'm using tab layout, not tab host

Comment: make custom tab

Comment: but how?
i tried adding linear layout in tab layout but it cause error because tab layout must only contain tab item

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661681/tab-icon-and-text-both-using-android-design-support-library

Comment: that's just custom to add icon and text, not for vertical mode sir

Comment: yes . but add your customlayout as linear - vertical

Comment: that only show custom layout for tab item sir, not tab layout.
then where should i adding linear layout? i think adding it in custom layout tab item will not work

Comment: check setupTabIcons() method in that link.R.layout.custom_tab is your custom linear vertical layout

Comment: i was sir, that code only used to add 1 tab and custom layout only for one tab. not for main layout to change the orientaion to vertical :)

Comment: really confused now, as per image you provided , that should work for you.

Comment: hmm, actually do u understand my question?
i want to create vertical tab layout, the image i show is what currently i have right now, but i want to make it in vertical mode.